# Observer functionality in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events

I can't get an observer to actually do anything in Ember.js. Basically, I have a Ember.Select dropdown menu, and want to bind some more action to the event of selecting the value in the dropdown. For example:

```
App.selectedPersonController = Ember.Object.create({
  person: null,
  personDidChange: function() {
    // do something here when the person changes
    console.log("PERSON CHANGED")
  }.observes('person')
});
```

And nothing is happening, even though the 'person' attribute is getting updated. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the fact that as of version pre4 you cannot set a property or observable upon the `Em.*.create()` function. You have to first use the `.extend()` function first and set all your properties and observables in that, then create that object.

As an example, take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/nv7y5/15/) that is working with the extend functionality. Then try to take it away by using only `create` and you'll see that the app no longer works.

Answer (score 3):

Or use createWithMixins() instead of create()