# Using Ember's "observes(..)" to observe some array's modification

Tags: ember.js

Ember's v1.0.0-rc.3 documentation of [`Ember.Array`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) says:

> You can use the methods defined in this module to access and modify array contents in a KVO-friendly way. You can also be notified whenever the membership if [sic] an array changes by changing the syntax of the property to **.observes('*myProperty.[]')**.

I tried to come up with a minimal example observing array changes, but couldn't make the observer fire. What does a working sample look like?

P.S. notice [this gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840760/923560).

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle of your non working example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh hey, there's my answer!

There's a couple of ways you can observe `Em.A()` properties. You have `.observes('a.[]')`, `.observes('a.@each')`, and `.observes('a.length')`. The concept is the same as any property in Ember though, you just have to directly manipulate the array and the observer should fire. Obviously using the `set` method is not going to work on an (Ember) array, so perhaps that is where you went wrong?

I have modified my old [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nv7y5/23/) to account for an observable array (I updated everything to the latest versions too).

I think it's important to bear in mind that the Ember Array is not actually an array - it's an object with some custom functions and properties that implement your usual array javascript functions. So you can't do something like: `Em.A() = [1,2,3]`, because the type of `Em.A` is an object, not an array.

Another useful note is that the ArrayControllers have a content of an Ember Array, meaning that you have to observe the **array of the content**, not the content itself (i.e. do not observe `arraycontroller.content`, but instead observe `arraycontroller.content.[]`).

This is why you have to observe the weird looking `prop.[]` property on an Ember Array, because the value of an Ember Array is not what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks Deif for this great feedback and the insights... yes, I didn't get the sample working for some similar gotcha: I used (... sticking to your jsFiddle example) `this.person.push(3)` instead of `this.person.pushObject(3)`. One needs to use the `pushObject(..)` method for having the `observes(..)` observers fire. [I guess this is what the Ember documentation means with "KVO-compliant"](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObject).